# Proving $AB$, $AC$ perpendicular to each other when vectors are median

Tags: analytic-geometry

I want to prove this claim:

> Triangle $ABC$ with $A(2,4,6),B(6,2,2),C(0,0,0)$ median, $AC$ and $BC$ perpendicular to each other.

What I did is to the $AB$, $BC$ make a dot product and thought it will be zero, but no result.
there is something I miss here.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you please define the term "cross-rib"?

Comment: Sorry, changed it to median.

Comment: Cannot understand what the question is. `AC`and `BC` cannot be orthogonal, given that both have a vertex in the origin and the other inside the first quarter.

Comment: I need to prove that the median in this triangle are orthogonal

Answer (score 1):

The median to $AC$ is $$\frac{A+C}{2}-B=(-5,0,-1), $$ and the median to $BC$ is $$\frac{B+C}{2}-A=(1,-3,-5) .$$
Their dot product is indeed zero.